# Dataframe saving in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, store

I have splitted a string into date and time and i am satifsied how it was done.
The output are data splitted into 4 columns).

Now i would like to save the dataframe into a csv file, but every time i do it, the old / origin data format will be stored (with 2 columns).

[Splitting a string into date and time (4 Columns)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVktk.png)

[unable to save the chnages i made on the data (2 Columns)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaGdw.png)

Comment: `df2 = df.assign(Date2=date2.dt.date, Time=date2.dt.time); df2.to_csv(...)` you need to assign the `df.assign` to a variable. `df.assign` returns a dataframe it does not update the original.

Comment: Could you write me a code how could be those changes saved in a csv file?

Comment: I did in my comment above `df2 = df.assign(Date2=date2.dt.date, Time=date2.dt.time); df2.to_csv(...)`

Comment: Sorry, i will try it out. Thank you very much for your time!